# Can I send myself a task summary mail using Outlook every morning?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, tasks

I use the 'Followup' and 'Task' feature of Outlook in order to track which items need additional work.

I would like an email report to be generated every morning to highlight tasks that are overdue, tasks that are due that day, and all pending tasks after that.

Any idea how I could accomplish this?

Since I put up a bounty, I am looking for a working solution. A nice to have would be the ability to customize the report that is sent to my email.

Comment: Not without writing a bit of code to query your task list. Theoretically it's not difficult: coding for Outlook isn't as bad as it used to be. You could then install it as an add-in or a service.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know of any "Add-Ons" that work this way, however you can go about this in a round about way.  This will require a [Toodledo](http://www.toodledo.com/) account (free) and then a [Toodledo/Outlook sync program](http://www.toodledo.com/connect_outlook.php) (also free).  Toodledo is a powerful online taks organization program that you can have email your daily summaries of tasks.  I personally use Toodledo with my iPhone and have been very pleased with it thus far.  To setup daily email of your tasks from toodledo follow these steps found [here](http://www.howardforums.com/printthread.php?t=1470247):

1. After Logon to Toodledo.com, select "Account Settings"
2. At the very top of the screen there's your logon email, select "edit" to the right
3. The next screen there's an option to have a daily reminder sent to your email.

There are currently two options for syncing with your Outlook: Chromatic Dragon and Ceptra Organizer.  I have NOT used either one, and there are possibly issues with Chromatic Dragon where it deletes your tasks, so I would try with a test account first before syncing with all your tasks in Outlook.

Answer (score 0):

Not natively. as comment above states

> Not without writing a bit of code to query your task list. Theoretically it's not difficult: coding for Outlook isn't as bad as it used to be. You could then install it as an add-in or a service. – [Randolph Potter](https://superuser.com/users/3463/randolph-potter) Feb 16 at 7:57

I would try http://www.outlookcode.com/
or you could try the book

[Microsoft Outlook programming:
jumpstart for administrators, power users, and developers](http://books.google.com/books?id=8M60Hy6B6LgC&dq=outlook%20coding&source=gbs_navlinks_s)

Answer (score -1):

You should use the Outlook Today screen

Find it by clicking the top-most folder of your e-mail account, probably the `Mailbox - First Last` heading

Here is a handy webpage that explains how to customize it any way you can imagine:
http://www.freeemailtutorials.com/outlook2007Tutorials/customizeOutlookToday.php

Comment: OP is specifically asking for an e-mail solution.